# Is form data / authentication / or any other request / response architecture affected by perm redirects?

Tags: c#, actionfilterattribute

- My application is running on multiple servers.
- I would like one of the servers to deal with a specific subset of api requests due to its interaction with cache. This server can be contacted by using the special CMS Url i gave it: `Config.CMSUrl`

I have the following code:

```
public enum ServerType
{
    CMS
}

public class RunOnServerAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ServerType Type;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case ServerType.CMS:
                if (!filterContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(Config.CMSUrl))
                {
                    var response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Moved);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri($"{Config.CMSUrl}/{filterContext.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery}");
                }

                break;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This should allow developers to add a simple attribute to an API method that will denote exactly where that method needs to run (so any methods that deal with interaction with cache should be directed through the cms server).

**Is this method safe to use in order to maintain authentication, form data and any other request/response architecture i may have in place? Or am i possibly risking something here?**

My other choice is to ensure that people calling the url in the first place correctly use the CMS Url rather than the normal api url... but my problem with that is the possible maintenance and human error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2008/01/24/anatomy-of-asp-net-forms-authentication-return-url/) as well.
When you redirect using your own scheme or url make sure you take care of any query parameters and encoded urls etc being passed. POST params will carry on as normal as they would be part of the request object.